# How to update cart price based on custom options

Tags: magento2

I have created a system fields where am adding price for the plans but am not able to update cart on custom option selection.

Below is my code need some guidance

```
class SetPrice implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface          
{
 protected $_request;
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
    array $data = []
 ) {
    $this->_request = $request;
 }

 public function execute(
    \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 ) {
    $postdata = $this->_request->getPost();
    $priceoption = $postdata['subscription_name']; // Your Drop Down field name goes here
    print_r($postdata);
    $logger = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
    // $logger->info( "My Value -- ".$postdata->getSubscriptionName() );
    $logger->info(print_r($postdata['subscription_name']) . "new option1");
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);
    $price = $price; //set your price here
    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
 }
 
}
```

**Helper where I have system fields.**

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
   
    public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

I am using this event **checkout_cart_product_add_after**

Answer (score 0):

Use the below plugin to get the updated price of the selected custom option.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price">
        <plugin name="AroundGetBasePrice" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\AroundGetBasePrice" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\AroundGetBasePrice.php

```
public function afterGetFinalPrice($subject, $result, $qty, $product)
{
 // your custom code
}
```

This might help you!

Comment: am using event observer approach